# React Native project crashes after distribution to testflight

Tags: xcode, react-native

React native project runs well in debug state. But after uploading the build to test flight, it crashes when I open the app.

So I found crash reports from the Organizer.

Below is the screenshot of the crash report.

[image: Screen Shot]

Comment: Have you tried running it in Release mode whilst it's plugged into XCode? You could then see the native logs and get a better stack trace.

Comment: Yes, and I found a problem. My js code had some problem and I fixed that. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer after long time research.
I ran by release mode and Xcode says which js code is wrong.
After I fixed that problem, everything is ok.